# Connection refused: AMQP server with nameko

Tags: windows, python-3.x, rabbitmq, nameko

Scenario:
We are trying to connect to RabbitMQ using nameko through AMQP server. 
Below is the traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Scripts\nameko.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\main.py", line 72, in main
    args.main(args)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\commands.py", line 85, in main
    main(args)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\run.py", line 182, in main
    run(services, config, backdoor_port=args.backdoor_port)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\cli\run.py", line 129, in run
    service_runner.start()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\runners.py", line 66, in start
    SpawningProxy(self.containers).start()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\utils\__init__.py", line 186, in spawning_method
    return list(pool.imap(call, self._items))
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenpool.py", line 244, in next
    val = self.waiters.get().wait()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 179, in wait
    return self._exit_event.wait()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\event.py", line 121, in wait
    return hubs.get_hub().switch()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\hub.py", line 295, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\hub.py", line 347, in run
    self.wait(sleep_time)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\selects.py", line 50, in wait
    writers.get(fileno, noop).cb(fileno)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 218, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\utils\__init__.py", line 181, in call
    return getattr(item, name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\messaging.py", line 225, in setup
    verify_amqp_uri(self.amqp_uri)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\amqp\utils.py", line 49, in verify_amqp_uri
    with transport.establish_connection():
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\nameko\amqp\utils.py", line 26, in init
    super(ConnectionTester, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 165, in init
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "d:\programfiles\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 95, in init
    raise socket.error(last_err)
OSError: [Errno 10061] WSAECONNREFUSED
```

Command we are using to run ,

```
nameko run --config configuration/nameko.yml test 3000 &
```

**nameko.yml** file contains below configuration,

```
AMQP_URI: amqp://guest:guest@10.10.10.10:5672    
WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS: 10.10.10.10:5672
```

**Operating system:** 
Windows 10 (Python code)
Linux (RabbitMQ server)

Please help us to solve this.

Comment: is your web server address really the same as your rabbitmq address? the web server address is where others browse to your server (so should be on the windows machine)

Comment: If you are using rabbitmq check if you can access the management plugin via port :15672 also your webserver address must use a different port for your app to run

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that a firewall is blocking incoming (on the rabbit server) or outgoing (from the windows server) connections?

can you e.g. telnet or otherwise verify that you can connect from the windows server to the linux server on the ipaddress and port in your config?